# Android Service On Notification Bar

Tags: android, android-service

I want to make an apps works like a music player. Which means, when the apps is minimize or backpressed, it will still running as service and showed on the notification bar. If user click on the running apps in the notification bar, it will retrieve and continue the apps as it is not restarting the apps.

Can anyone help me? I don't really have the idea on this service. This is my first time learning service.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the logic in overridden `Activity.onPause()` method:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
  NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)ctx.getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
  Notification notification = createNotificationSomehow( .... );
  nm.notify( TRAY_ID, notification );
}
```